# Differences between TeX/LaTeX and Script/GML

Tags: macros, tex-core, xml, tex-history

I often see people saying that SGML and LaTeX are different because SGML is made for defining markup languages, while LaTeX is using TeX macros to simulate content markups. However, SGML is based on GML, and GML itself, from what I have read, is also just macros on top of Script. I found a manual of Script/370 and it seems also very primitive just like TeX.

Based on this, can we conclude that SGML and LaTeX are just similar things? If not, what are some more fundamental differences?

Added XML tag because it evolves from SGML and perhaps someone will have some insights on that direction.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Although LaTeX and SGML both have a goal of shoehorning text into a markup straitjacket, SGML is much more rigid (but also more amenable to conformance checking).  I've never used or investigated Script, but am reasonably familiar with TeX itself.  It would be possible with TeX to define an SGML-like structured input convention, but LaTeX isn't quite it.

Comment: You might find that the XML Slack forum is a good way of reaching people who were involved in the history: see https://www.xml.com/news/2020-04-slack-workspace-for-the-xml-community/

Comment: @barbarabeeton Why was LaTeX not designed to be as strict as SGML though? Or put it in another way, why didn't someone design a more structured layer on top of TeX in a way similar to how GML was designed on top of Script?

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for the link. I'll take a look.

Comment: @haha -- Why wasn't LaTeX designed more like GML (I believe SGML wasn't yet in existence)?  Leslie Lamport designed what he needed.  He's the only person who can answer that question.